# Foreach loop within $message of PHP mail() function

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a loop that enters each non-empty text field into a database:

```
foreach ($guests as $guest) {

    if ($guest !== "") {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$guest', '$night', '$date') ") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I'd like to also print each of these names into an email, which I presume somehow containing the output within the $message variable in mail(). How is this best achieved?

On a side note, changing from by editing $headers is proving very temperamental. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($guests as $guest) {
    if ($guest !== "") {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestlists (guest, night, date) VALUES('$guest', '$night', '$date')") or die(mysql_error());
        $names[] = $guest;
    }
}
$message = "Guests: ".implode(", ", $names).". ";
```

I hope you're sure that `$guest, $night, $date` variables are already passed through `mysql_real_escape_string` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way of using <br> as the separator?

Comment: Of course. Just replace `", "` to `"<br>"` in `implode` call.

Comment: I tried that but my email didn't render the HTML. Is this a problem with my client? Or could '\r' work?

Comment: Create another question and provide the code you're using to send emails in it.